# Learning curve function on Scikit learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, scoring

I want to plot a learning curve for my regression problem, using RMSE as a "scoring parameter".

How do I set a different "scoring" parameter? Seems that "scoring" is deprecated in the learning curve function...

Can anyone help me? Or recommend me another function...

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html there is `scoring` parameter.

If you mean `plot_learning_curve` function from there https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-learning-curve-py

You could change it like this:

```
def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, axes=None, ylim=None, cv=None,
                        n_jobs=None, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5), scoring='metric'):
...

    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, fit_times, _ = \
        learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs,
                       train_sizes=train_sizes,
                       return_times=True, scoring=scoring)
...
```

Comment: Just adding another question, how can I set "squared" parameter set to "False" in "neg_mean_squared_error" (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error)  to obtain RMSE in this case?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer you can use `make_scorer` for this

Comment: I got it! Thanks again :D